# How can I add a progressive number in different field in excel?

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an excel file with a sushi restaurant menu,
in the first column I have a progressive number 1,2,3,4,... and in the second column I have the products onigiri, fried, ecc...
Can I edit the second column simultaneously replacing the name of the product with "001 onigiri, 002 fried, 003 sashimi, 004 ecc..." without changing them manually?

I searched for some formulas but I dont find anything

Comment: A formula cannot replace the value in a cell while referring to itself.  You will need a third column that contains the formula: `=TEXT(A2,"000") & " " & B2`

Comment: I can add that the second column can be hidden for convenience after the result is added into third column.